# Easy in-code access of application configuration

Tags: java, design-patterns, configuration, software-design

I'm facing a design problem in my application related to its configuration.

Let's assume we have some huge domain, which can be divided into several subdomains. Each subdomain should use the same as generic as possible code and all the differences should be stored in the configuration - one for each subdomain. Subdomain configuration items can be present in many subdomains and some of them can be unique to only one subdomain. Simple example to imagine this: some taxes values in different countries can be the same but additionally there could be values, which are not present in any other country.

Most of the configuration items are arrays of some objects and I would like to have quick access to every item via some constants just like enums because of the business logic. I don't want to keep loaded values in an array, list or similar structure and prepare code to search for correct value each time - I'm afraid of performance loss.

My idea is was to create some generic abstract class keeping data in a list and for each subdomain create subclass with constants referring to each value but it does not sound good from maintenance perspective.

I'm considering keeping such configuration in YAML or JSON format.

Are there any design patterns, which helps to achieve satisfying results? Or maybe my whole concept is wrong? This configuration is the basis of whole application and I want to avoid potential issues with it when the project will be too advanced.

Comment: *I'm afraid of performance loss?* what performance loss?

Comment: Lots of iterations over the array/list just to find desired value. One of the requirements is to run business logic code as fast as possible and such lookups to the configuration will be very often. I'm not expecting single search for the value will be much slower than accessing it via some constant but I'm afraid of accumulation of such operations.

Comment: a different data structure maybe to speed up the look-up? a map?

Comment: Yes, I'm considering that too. I could use constant strings to easiliy access the values and the maintenance would not be so painful.

Comment: How many values are there in your configuration?

Comment: The configuration is still growing and I don't know for now how many items will be there. For the time being the largest list contains around 50 elements. I would like to simply access any of them in code just like referring to constant.

Answer (score 0):

Since you express a desire to access configuration values (almost) as quickly as accessing constant values, this suggests that the configuration data will be read only at application start-up and will *not* be reread dynamically during application running. This presents two possibilities.

The first possibility is to do the following at application start-up. Read the entire configuration file into an object called `cfg` that provides operations such as `String lookupString(String name)`, `int lookupInt(String name)` and `boolean lookupBoolean(String name)`. Then use those operations to query configuration values specific to a sub-domain and store those values in a Java object whose definition is specific to the sub-domain. For example, `TaxConfig`, `LoggingConfig`, `CountryConfig`, `DatabaseConfig` and so on can be classes that store configuration data specific to their respective sub-domains. In this way, the relatively slow lookup API of the `cfg` object is used just at application start-up time to populate the `XXXConfig` objects that provide lots of getters and setters for named configuration variables (stored as fields). In this way, the latency-sensitive code in your application call make calls such as `taxConfig.getVatRate()`. Since such calls will be trivial (they just return the value of a field) they will be fast. If you declare those getter operations to be `final`, then the JIT compiler might even inline calls to them, thus speeding up access.

The second possibility arises *if* the configuration data is going to be static for months/years at a time. In this (unlikely) case, you could write a code generator that reads the (concise) input configuration file and generates (more verbose) Java classes containing constant values. Then compile your application code against these classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I started development with approach similar to the first proposed by you. I was also considering second option because it perfectly fits to my case. Whole sub-domain configuration would be stored in single file and access would be as fast as possible. However I feel writing my own code generator is not worth to spend a time.

Comment: Writing a code generator might be simpler than you think. Google the "Apache Velocity" template engine to find a tutorial about it. It *might* suit your needs.

Comment: Brilliant idea. I'll definitely take a look on that. I have a little experience with Freemarker template engine but I've never thought about it in any other way than using it for creation of dynamic websites.